# How to perform validation on Wix UI Edit control

Tags: wix

How can i do validation on a wix Edit control and make the Next button be available only if user entered some string (cannot be empty)

```
<Property Id="BASEKITPATH" Value=" " />
```

```
<Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUINext)">
  <Condition Action="disable"><![CDATA[BASEKITPATH = " "]]></Condition> 
  <Condition Action="enable"><![CDATA[BASEKITPATH <> " "]]></Condition>
</Control>
```

With the above code, the Next button is becoming ReadOnly when the installer starts, but when i change the text the Next button nothing changes and the Next stays ReadOnly

What seems to be the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known limitation of the underlying Windows Installer.  It has scenarios like this where the ControlConditions won't work because they don't validate propreties that have changed while the UI is shown.

The typical work around is to use mutually exclusive ControlEvents.  One to call SpawnDialog to display a validation error message and one to go to the next applicable dialog.

Comment: can you give an example? or link to one?

Answer (score 1):

If somebody looks for example he can find it in the source code of Wix.
Open "WixUI_InstallDir.wxs" and check "InstallDirDlg" Dialog.

Sample from code:

```
        <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="LicenseAgreementDlg">1</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="SetTargetPath" Value="[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR]" Order="1">1</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="DoAction" Value="WixUIValidatePath" Order="2">NOT WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="InvalidDirDlg" Order="3"><![CDATA[NOT WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH AND WIXUI_INSTALLDIR_VALID<>"1"]]></Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg" Order="4">WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH OR WIXUI_INSTALLDIR_VALID="1"</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Property="_BrowseProperty" Value="[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR]" Order="1">1</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="BrowseDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>
```

Check the "SpawnDialog" event.